# Use classes in jar file in java program in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, executable-jar

I have converted my java code into .jar now i want to use the class in that jar file in another class, so i am unable to do so. Thank you very much for any kind of help!

Comment: The easy way, if you know the fully qualified name of the class - and it's "there", is type it out and press `ctr+shift+o`; you should get a list of possible imports to fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Eclipse, right click on your project where you want to use your jar. Select "Properties", there select "Java Build Path". Under "Libraries" you can add the JAR (if you copied it to a lib folder in your project), or select an external JAR (if you don't have it in your lib folder).

When this is done, you can use it in your code. Just use the class, and when a red scribble is underlining your class name, hover over it and select "Import 'Classname' (this.is.your.package)". Alternately, you can let Eclipse auto import the most logical package by pressing "CTRL+Shift+O" (hotkey to auto import)

Answer (score 0):

Add the jar in the new project classpath and then you should be able to use the classes.

Comment: i have added it in new project as an external jar but how to use it in code?

Comment: yes i am new to java look once i have included that jar file in new project in which i want to use it so how will I make reference to the class present in that file?

Comment: If you have the right classes in your jar, then Eclipse should help you with the autocomplete feature in finding them also if classpath is set correctly. Just start typing them and also Eclipse will import them accordingly.